# Are 40pin to 44pin IDE adapters 'smart' or 'dumb'? (dumb is good)

Tags: motherboard, pata

I want to connect an old laptop drive to an old desktop motherboard. Do these adapters passively send and receive signals from the ide port? Or do they have logic/chips in them?

I'm going to use the motherboard to [ATA Secure Erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) the hard drive. USB-IDE adapters don't work for this purpose, as far as I can make out: see [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6970/usb-to-ide-adapter-that-can-send-the-ata-secure-erase-command) for the issue (a chipset that supported SCSI ATA Translation is what I *thought* I would need to make ATA Secure Erase work, but it didn't make any difference). If the 40 to 44 pin adapter is active/smart, there's a good chance it won't be able to interpret the necessary commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most 40 to 44 pin IDE adapters, such as the [Rosewill RCW-616](http://www.rosewill.com/rosewill-rcw-616-laptop-2-5-to-desktop-3-5-ide-hard-drive-adapter-converter.html), are completely passive or dumb. The only real difference between the 40 and 44 pin connections aside from the physical size are the power is added into the IDE connector on a 44 pin interface rather than being a separate connection on devices with a 40 pin interface, meaning adding a logic circuit of any kind would just increase the cost without any usefulness (although if memory serves me correctly, some notebook drives did not have Master/Slave jumpers, and some adapters had a minimal logic circuit just to allow you to jumper that setting on the adapter board, but I could be wrong since none of the ones in our bench have them).

Also, a USB-IDE interface intended for a 44 pin laptop hard drive should work fine, although I am not sure what you mean by "it won't be able to interpret the necessary commands" since the only thing it does is place the controller on the USB bus rather than directly on the PCI bus, the commands should all be identical.

Comment: *I am not sure what you mean by "it won't be able to interpret the necessary commands"* see edit I am about to make